# Parallel iterating and processing a tuple's fields

Tags: rust

The slice method [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut) returns a tuple of 2 sub-slices. I want to process them in parallel using the [Rayon](https://crates.io/crates/rayon) crate's `par_iter()` but that iterator does not support tuple iteration.

I thought of converting the tuple of 2 to a list and then applying `par_iter()`, but I have not found any syntax to convert a tuple into a slice or vector. So how do I process the tuple in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is probably not to use `par_iter`, but instead to call [`spawn`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.2.0/rayon/fn.spawn.html) twice, possibly inside a [`scope`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.2.0/rayon/fn.scope.html):

```
fn doit(v: &mut [i32]) {
    for x in v.iter_mut() {
        *x *= 2;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    rayon::scope(|s| {
        let mid = data.len() / 2;
        let (a, b) = data.split_at_mut(mid);
        s.spawn(move |_| doit(a));
        s.spawn(move |_| doit(b));
    });
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9704dcc0f1982a2a08e9faad76877467)

Comment: i got this error in my IDE `T cannot be sent between threads safely`. It underlies at `spawn`. Additional message: `help: within [T], the trait std::marker::Send is not implemented for T
help: consider adding a where T: std::marker::Send bound`

Comment: how do I use it with generic type array?

Comment: Do what the error message suggests: add `where T: std::marker::Send` to your generic declaration.